# Использование Java функций в ресурсах Maven

Tags: java, maven

Возник вопрос при работе с ресурсами, надеюсь на вашу помощь.

Есть YML файл, лежащий в папке "src/main/resources", в котором я могу использовать переменные Maven через конструкцию `${}`, соответственно вопрос:

Могу ли я использовать Java функции в данном файле, а конкретно - `${artifactId.toLowerCase()}`?

Comment: Не знаю такого способа. В качестве альтернативы можно создать отдельное свойство, в которое записать `artifactId`  в нижнем регистре. Посмотрите два варианта здесь: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10521860/property-autocapitalization-in-maven

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В текущей версии `Maven` нет подобного способа, возможно имеет место написание подобного плагина.